# not getting value with push array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

In the following AJAX function, I'm trying to implement push array. There is problem with that array: I am not getting that array value in post in alert I am getting that value in array but when passing that value it's undefined.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function getmember()
  {
    var myarray = new Array();
    myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
    alert(myarray);
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "getmember.php", 
      data: myarray,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
          "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
        );

        alert("bb");
      }
    });
    return false;
  } 
  </script>

<select name="group_id" class="group_id" onChange="getmember();" multiple>

             <?php
               $selectGroup = "SELECT group_id,group_name FROM `group`";
               $groupRes           = mysql_query($selectGroup);
               while($row1 =  mysql_fetch_array($groupRes))
               {
                 echo '<td><option value="'.$row1['group_id'].'">'.$row1['group_name'].'</option></td>';
               }
             ?>
          </select>
```

Comment: Do you mean the alert(myArray) shows nothing? can you show the HTML for .group_id?

Comment: @AmmarCSE html code updated.

Comment: where is `group_id` class name in HTML you posted?

Comment: Some punctuation in your prose would really help to make it understandable. I've added some where I could figure it out, but there's more missing after `I am not getting` where I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: @das-g where is problem in my code

Comment: @AmmarCSE in alert i m getting value but when i trying post that value is give me error undefined

Comment: I was talking about your **prose** (your text above your code), not about your code. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push value with `key` and define variable `myarray` as global

```
   var myarray; 
   function getmember()
   {
     myarray = [];
     myarray.push({'group_id':$(".group_id").val()});
    // your code.
   }
```

as discussed to post data like below URL

```
http://localhost/ashutosh/getmember.php?group_id=1,2,3,4
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
 var myarray;
 function getmember()
 {
   myarray = [];
   myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
   // your code.

    url: "getmember.php", 
    data:'group_id='+myarray.join(),
 }
```

Comment: now i want to used this id in select query what should i do for it me implode that in my php file or that is possible with something else

Comment: chat option is block at my work place see this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: SELECT * FROM  `your table`   WHERE `group_id` IN ( 1,2,3 );

Comment: suppose if i am selecting one value after that i am selecting another value than it pass first value two time..

Comment: my select query is like this                                                              $group_id = $myarray[];

$selectGroup = "SELECT contact_id FROM addressgroup WHERE group_id IN($group_id)";

Comment: check my updated answer . how to clear array  and in query pass group_id which you get in post no need to explode in ` $group_id = $_POST['group_id'];`

Comment: let me create example

Comment: i already have getmember.php file in my folder still it give me error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: there is some error in your php code either syntax error or mysql error